# When I Parent my rig, it will offset my model. Why?

Tags: rigging

I am trying to rig a simple Bvh file to a basic model but Once I do the model is offset of the rig. I parent it with automatic weight. What am I doing wrong?[image]

[image]

Comment: When I rig the model with a normal rig, everything works normally but when I try to rig the model with a Bvh rig that's when the model gets offset.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, you have to parent the bvh file to the model in Rest Position.